# Sitecore: argument out of range when page editor is enabled

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.2

The only goal right now is to run the Sitecore page editor without issues. The error comes from the following URL:

```
http://localhost/sitecore/shell/Applications/WebEdit/WebEditRibbon.aspx?db=master&id={guid}&la=en&vs=1&url=%2F&mode=edit&sc_pagesite=website&trf=%2Ftemp%2Fdiagnostics%2Ftrace_{guid}.xml&prf=%2Ftemp%2Fdiagnostics%2Fprofile_{guid}.xml&dev={guid}
```

I'm getting this exception when I open any page with the page editor enabled:

```
16028 13:57:46 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_webedit_webeditribbon_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\3d565cb3\44f479ba\App_Web_pyaedh12.0.cs:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallMethod(Type type, Object obj, String methodName, Boolean includeNonPublic, Boolean includeInherited, Boolean includeStatic, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Message: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
Parameter name: startIndex
Source: mscorlib
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.LinkBuilder.GetItemPathElement(Item item, SiteInfo site)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.LinkBuilder.BuildItemUrl(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider.GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Providers.LinkProvider.GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebEditUtil.GetItemUrl(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderTreecrumbGo(HtmlTextWriter output, Item item)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.RenderTreecrumb(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.WebEditRibbonForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
```

The page renders fine when the page editor is disabled.

Running versions:

- Sitecore 7.2.
- ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 (also tried 5.1.3).

I have tried removing anything that's related to Sitecore in layouts/renderings, but that error still occurs. I realize that it can be impossible to figure out what's going on without seeing the configuration files, but here's to hoping someone have stumbled onto this error before!

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the literal URL? There aren't any actual GUIDs in it, which would be a problem. Also, is the site you're editing called "website" in the web.config?

Comment: No it's not the literal URL, I've just "hidden" the GUIDs. And yes, it's the one called "website", I have changed the rootPath attribute to `/sitecore/content/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the rootPath attribute. It appears that it cannot be two levels below `/sitecore/content`. When I changed it from `/sitecore/content/foo/bar` to `/sitecore/content/foo` it worked again. Hopefully a Sitecore veteran can explain why this is!